# Map a Complex Array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, sorting, mapping

```
    array = [{:variant_id=>51, :product_id=>14, :position=>2, :price=>80.0}, {:variant_id=>52, :product_id=>14, :position=>3, :price=>200.0}, {:variant_id=>14, :product_id=>5, :position=>1, :price=>0.0}, {:variant_id=>15, :product_id=>5, :position=>2, :price=>100.0}, {:variant_id=>16, :product_id=>5, :position=>3, :price=>210.0}, {:variant_id=>17, :product_id=>5, :position=>4, :price=>225.0}, {:variant_id=>63, :product_id=>17, :position=>2, :price=>100.0}]
```

Each product_id has 4 variants. Each variant has a position (1,2,3, or 4). Each variant has a price.

Example

Product id: 5
has variant_id: 10, 11, 12, 13
variant_id: 10 has the price $100
variant_id: 11 has the price $200
variant_id: 12 has the price $300
variant_id: 13 has the price $400

I want to map this array of hashes into an array of hashes that are structured like the following
{product_id: 5, price: "100|200|300|400"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After posting my answer I noticed that it was virtually identical to @Ismael's answer, which he had posted a few minutes earlier.  Accordingly, I've changed my answer to illustrate an alternative approach. I did this after you selected my answer.  If you would like to move the green checkmark to Ismael's answer, or to one that may be added later, by all means do so.

```
array = [{:variant_id=>51, :product_id=>14, :position=>2, :price=>80.0},
         {:variant_id=>52, :product_id=>14, :position=>3, :price=>200.0},
         {:variant_id=>14, :product_id=>5,  :position=>1, :price=>0.0},
         {:variant_id=>15, :product_id=>5,  :position=>2, :price=>100.0},
         {:variant_id=>16, :product_id=>5,  :position=>3, :price=>210.0},
         {:variant_id=>17, :product_id=>5,  :position=>4, :price=>225.0},
         {:variant_id=>63, :product_id=>17, :position=>2, :price=>100.0}]

array.each_with_object({}) { |h,g|
  g.update({ h[:product_id] => h[:price].to_s }) { |_,o,n| "#{o}|#{n}" } }
   .map { |k,v| { product_id: k, price: v } }
  #=> [{:product_id=>14, :price=>"80.0|200.0"},
  #    {:product_id=>5,  :price=>"0.0|100.0|210.0|225.0"},
  #    {:product_id=>17, :price=>"100.0"}]
```

This uses the form of [Hash#update](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Hash.html#method-i-update) (a.k.a. `Hash#merge!`) that takes a block. When the hash `{h[:product_id] => h[:price].to_s}` (where `h` is an element of `array`) is being merged into the initially-empty hash `g`, if both hashes contain the key `h[:product_id]`, the block is called upon to determine the value for that key in the merged hash.  Three values are passed to the block: the shared key (which I am not using, so I've replaced the associated block variable for the key with the placeholder `_`), the current value in the merged hash `g`, `g[:product_id]` (assigned to the block variable `o`) and the value for the hash being merged, `h[:price].to_s` (assigned to the block variable `n`).  As shown, the value should be `"#{o}|#{n}"`.

The first step produces the hash:

```
h = array.each_with_object({}) { |h,g|
  g.update({h[:product_id] => h[:price].to_s}) {|_,o,n| "#{o}|#{n}"}}
  #=> {14=>"80.0|200.0", 5=>"0.0|100.0|210.0|225.0", 17=>"100.0"}
```

Aside: you may consider stopping here.

The last step is to map each key-value pair of this hash to a hash, to produce an array of hashes:

```
h.map { |k,v| {product_id: k, price: v } }
```

Comment: Cool. :) We think the same way

Comment: Cary to save the day again! Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like group_by, map and reduce and friends should help you here.

This should work

```
grouped = array.group_by {|x| x[:product_id]}
```

This gets you a hash with `product_id => hashes_with_this_product_id`

You can now map and join those values

```
grouped.map do |id, arr|
  prices = arr.map {|h| h[:price].to_s}.join('|')
  {product_id: id, price: prices}
end
```

I havent tested but this should help you a little

Comment: Fixed :) I'm actualy writing on my phone. And it's really hard to write code on this thing. Glad I could help you.